# How to show discount percentage over the image of my products?

Tags: magento2

What I am trying to achieve is this, I have configurable products I want to display the percentage of the discount as a label on the image maybe in the top right corner. **I've managed to display it by using this code:**

```
       <span>
         <?php
         $item = $block->getSaleableItem();
         $_savePercent = 100 - round(((float)$priceModel->getAmount()->getValue() / (float)$finalPriceModel->getAmount()->getValue()) * 100);
         echo '<b style="color:#008000">'.$_savePercent . '% off </b>';
        ?>
      </span>
```

This edit is placed in my final_price.phtml file. However with this I am displaying the % Discount in my product page as well. Because I will have different stylings for both the pages I want to display it seperatly once in the catalog and once on the product page. Is there a way to do it? I do not want to use ***extensions***.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/boris1988/module-product-labels
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuDeJ.png)

[image]

`composer require bperevyazko/module-product-label`
`bin/magento module:enable BPerevyazko_ProductLabel`
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
And configure it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).